Django & Cloudinary - Admin Panel Image Upload Returns Error "This res.cloudinary.com page can’t be found"
I have the following Teacher model:
class Teacher(models.Model):

...    
    # Image Field
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='teacher_images/', blank=False, null=False)  

    # Metadata
...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Teacher"
        verbose_name_plural = "Teachers"
        ordering = ['name']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['email']),  
            models.Index(fields=['department']),  
        ]
    





        

And in my settings.py:
cloudinary.config( 
    cloud_name = "XXXXXXX", 
    api_key = "XXXXXXX", 
    api_secret = "XXXXXXX", 
    secure=True
)

# Set default storage backend to Cloudinary
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dce5bvfok/image/upload/'

Yet when I navigate to the admin panel to upload an image, the URL formats correctly. For example: https://res.cloudinary.com/dce5bvfok/image/upload/teacher_images/hsu2-min.JPG. However, I can't actually view the image as I receive this error when navigating to the generated URL:
This res.cloudinary.com page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://res.cloudinary.com/dce5bvfok/image/upload/teacher_images/hsu2-min.JPG
HTTP ERROR 404

Does anyone know why this is occurring and how to rectify it?

Do the files certainly still exist in your account with the public_id value you're trying to use to access them? Is it possible your app is deleting the assets later (e.g. if they're becoming orphaned?). Also, please note that you posted your private API credentials here, so I've rotated your keys from our side to prevent unauthorized access to your account.

I don't know... I'm uploading through the admin panel like you saw above and I don't have a public_id value set. My app does not store the assets, I am trying to store them on Cloudinary

Do you have Pillow installed?
